# Partition create on kali linux

Tags: linux, partitioning, kali-linux, extended-desktop

I  can't unsized any partition I have many free space but Not working setting option in this images

[image]

[image]

Please suggest me.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can't decrease an unallocated partition. You can however add that spae to another partition.

Comment: I tried that already many terms but didn't work

Comment: I know from windows that there is something like a max partitions limit. but not sure if its also for linux.

Comment: this looks like an `MBR` or `msdos`-type partition table. you should be able to create a new **primary** partition in the space shown.  if you boot from a livecd and don't mount `sda1`, you should also be able to extend `sda1` or `sda2` into that space.  the other partitions are **logical** partitions (inside `sda2`), so extending `sda2` first should allow you to extend `sda9` (or create `sda10`, or shift 7/8/9 and extend `sda6`, or whatever).  as @Kamil notes, you'll need to perform moves or resizes on unmounted partitions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to unomount partitions before resizing them. If they are used by your system you should shutdown and boot using live cd/usb, and then change partitions sizes.